# How does AWS run active health check if Health* properties are not specified for HTTP and TCP?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-elb, nlb

I have two target groups:

```yaml
  ATargetGroup:
    Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::TargetGroup
    Properties:
      VpcId:
        Fn::ImportValue: !Join [ "", [ !FindInMap [ EnvironmentMap, !Ref Environment, VpcStackName ], "-VPCID" ] ]
      Port: 9001
      Protocol: TCP
      TargetType: ip
      TargetGroupAttributes:
        - Key: deregistration_delay.timeout_seconds
          Value: '30'
        - Key: preserve_client_ip.enabled
          Value: true

  BTargetGroup:
    Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::TargetGroup
    Properties:
      VpcId:
        Fn::ImportValue: !Join [ "", [ !FindInMap [ EnvironmentMap, !Ref Environment, VpcStackName ], "-VPCID" ] ]
      Port: 9002
      Protocol: TCP
      TargetType: ip
      TargetGroupAttributes:
        - Key: deregistration_delay.timeout_seconds
          Value: '30'
        - Key: preserve_client_ip.enabled
          Value: true
```

Both are forwarding traffic to the same containers.
On port `9001` I server HTTP traffic. While `9002` servers raw TCP traffic.

How does AWS perform health checks on the registered targets if none of the `Health*` properties (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-elasticloadbalancingv2-targetgroup.html) are specified on any of the target groups in my cloudformation template?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the link you shared, if the health check path isn't specified AWS will check with the default health check paths.
To be sure about it, and judging  on previous experience AWS WILL CHECK with its default health check paths so you better specify them if your applications have different paths.

Comment: 1. If `/` is being used then my application would respond with a `404`.
2. Also how does the target group know that it's an HTTP protocol, as I have specified it as a TCP protocol?

Comment: 1. yes then you need to configure 404 as a healthy response, or just configure your health check route.  2. Hypertext Transfer Protocol (HTTP) is a member of the TCP/IP family. Each server or client on a TCP/IP internet is identified by a numeric IP (Internet Protocol) address. so specifiyng a tcp port is not a problem. If your issue is solved please feel free to close this thread and mark it as solved. Good luck !

Comment: I haven't configured 404 as a healthy response anywhere and still the targets are healthy.